# How to apply Laplacian Eigenmap on high-dimensional time series?

Tags: time-series, dimensionality-reduction, graph-theory, manifold-learning

Suppose I have a time series of T observations for M features

My question in application of Laplacian Eigenmap is when forming an adjacency matrix $A_{i,j}$, should I create an T by T matrix for $A_{i,j}$ = exp(-||(observation at t = i) - (observation at t = j)||$^2$/$w$) for some value of w if i'th observation is within k nearest neighbor of j'th observation?

Or should the adjacency matrix be M by M and instead replace (observation at t = i) with (i'th feature) ?

Comment: In what sense is $A$ actually an adjacency matrix (which typically has only zeros or ones for its components)?  What could it mean to replace an observation at time $i$ (note that $i$ is a *time*) with the "i'th feature" (where now evidently $i$ is an index between $1$ and $M$)?

Comment: I thought I have to think of all those T observations as "nodes" and connect them if they're within k-nearest neighbor and the weight would be based on the Gaussian kernel, which is based on the Euclidean distance. So, in a sense, I will get a sparse T by T matrix. But doing that won't capture the non-linear relationship between the features. So, was I think of correct? or should I think of those M time series as nodes and create M by M matrix? (thus finding the weight between i'th time series and j'th time series)